# How to hide a folder in the AS400 server?

Tags: file-permissions, ibm-midrange

I can list all folders(project folders) when  i use  shell commands in the as400 screen.
I have accesss to this server and all project folders or directories are listed in my zend studio.
But i cannot see one folder and its subdirectories.
What will be the reason for this?
Did administrator hide this folder ?  How ? Where can i check?

Comment: Instead of giving answer or suggesion or atleast comments , if question looks strange suddenly people click on close. Why you want to close atleast comment that cowards

Comment: Thanks David. Can you suggest where can i check and set the permission

Comment: Does your Zend Studio log in with the same User ID as the one you use to issue shell commands?  When you say you are issuing shell commands on the AS400 are you using WRKLNK if so take option 9 to work with the authority for the folder which is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can "hide" folders by removing authorization to them. But if I understand you correctly, you have authorization since you can see them on the green-screen (assuming that you are using the same login).

As a sidenote: If you aren't getting anywhere here. You could also ask your question on [WEB400](http://murl.me/web400) there are many using Zend Studio on the IBM i there. They are quite friendly and can at least point you in a direction.